# Conversion error in STM32 MIPI-DSI app note?

Tags: stm32, conversion

I'm trying to teach myself about the MIPI-DSI interface on STM32 F4 MCUs and came across this graphic and accompanying description:
[image: app note possible error]

As I understand it, the data being transferred is actually 0x94 and 0x0E, and the person writing the document just goofed on their conversion. Just double checking in case. This is only one of many issues I've found in this document, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's wrong. STM really needs to get some editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure looks like a typo to me.

The only way the values 0x92 and 0x07 would make sense is if each byte is split into 4-bit nybbles, and the least-significant nybble is sent first, but the nybble itself is sent MSbit first — which would be truly bizarre.

The more likely explanation is that the author forgot to flip it in his head when reading the waveforms.